# i want place order virtual server with mutiple quantity ,how i can generate order container

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Hi all i have used softlayer api using python

i need place virtual server with multiple quantity ,how generate order container ??
i have like this,

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.Client(username='XXXXXX',api_key='xxxxxx')     
vmorderparmers = {
            'hostname':'testhost',
            'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
            'datacenter': 'sjc01',
            'startCpus':1,
            'maxMemory': 1024,

            'localDiskFlag': True,
            'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
            'operatingSystemReferenceCode':'CENTOS_6_64',
            "blockDevices": [
                {
                    "device": "0",
                    "diskImage": {
                        "capacity": 100
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
oc = client['Virtual_Guest'].generateOrderTemplate(vmorderparmers)
```

after i have check qunatity

```
oc['quantity']
```

give one how i change that
suppose i change quantity like this

> oc['quantity']=2
>
> result=client['Product_Order'].placeOrder(oc)

i got error invalid order contianer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to order several virtual servers, in your case the method [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::generateOrderTemplate](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/generateOrderTemplate) returns the container type [SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest) that can be send to the method [SoftLayer_Product_Order::verifyOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder) or [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder).

If you look the example for Virtual Servers in the [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) page. You'll notice that you need to modify the **quantity** AND **virtualGuest** parameters as following.

```
'virtualGuests': [
            {
                'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
                'hostname': 'testhost1'
            },
            {
                'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
                'hostname': 'testhost2'
            },
            {
                'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
                'hostname': 'testhost3'
            }
        ],
'quantity': 3
```

Then your python code should looks like this:

```
"""
Create a VSI using the simplified way.

The script creates an order template by using the method generateOrderTemplate(), we'll
modify the response in order to create several virtual servers.
See below for more information.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/generateOrderTemplate/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# To get the configuration options to create the server call the
# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getCreateObjectOptions method.
vmorderparmers = {
    'hostname': 'testhost',
    'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
    'datacenter': {'name': 'sjc01'},
    'startCpus': 1,
    'maxMemory': 1024,
    'localDiskFlag': True,
    'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'CENTOS_6_64',
    'blockDevices': [
        {
            'device': '0',
            'diskImage': {'capacity': 100}
        }
    ]
}

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    container = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].generateOrderTemplate(vmorderparmers)

    # In order to create several VSI we modify the following parameters in the response
    container['quantity'] = 3

    # If you set quantity greater than 1 then you need to define
    # hostname/domain per virtual server you wish to order.
    container['virtualGuests'] = [
        {
            'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
            'hostname': 'testhost1'
        },
        {
            'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
            'hostname': 'testhost2'
        },
        {
            'domain': 'exampledomain.com',
            'hostname': 'testhost3'
        }
    ]

    """
    Now we are able to verify or place the order.
    verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
    placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
    that you can use for your records.
    """
    receipt = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(container)
    print (receipt)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """
    print('Unable to create the VSI. %s, %s ' % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

I hope this help you.